# net_scheduler holding wakelock

Tags: android, performance

I have observed that on some occasions, net_scheduler keeps acquiring wakelock repeatedly over short durations and prevents my android device from sleep.

From logcat, I am not able to obtain any conclusive information why this might be happening. Clearly some of the gms services are active.

Can somebody suggest when is there a higher chance for this to occur from the perspective of gms services.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be coming from [GcmNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager), which schedules network-oriented tasks, so that Google Play services is able to batch network operations across the system.

Also if you would use more advanced scheduling like [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android), internally the GcmNetworkManager would be used.

Answer (score 0):

You may find a tool "My android tools pro 1.6.0" and find "google play service" in following item, them disable the entry after each:

1. Service: TaskExecutionService
2. Broadcast Receiver: SchedulerInternalReceiver, SchedulerReveiver

And everything should be fine :)